# Battery terminal connection issue

Tags: battery, battery-drain

I have a dodge caravan 2012 and I recently got an electronic anti-rust device installed.

3 weeks after, I experienced a first problem.  I started the engine then it stopped after 2 seconds.  I restarted it and it worked (the radio hour has been reset to 12:00)

2 weeks later, I tried to start the engine but nothing happened... there was absolutely no power coming from the battery.  My first reaction was to blame the electronic anti-rust device, which could be draining the battery.  However, when I installed the booster cable on my battery terminal connection, the power came back and there was enough power to start the engine...

As the booster cable wasn't plugged to any power source at the other end, does it confirm the problem is linked to a loose battery terminal connection (fixed by the charger cable clamp) or could it be something else?

Comment: What is an electronic anti-rust system? I can't see any possible way that could work... Sounds like snake-oil to me...

Comment: It may be a scam... but for 80$ I decided to give a try.  Here a [link](http://www.otoprotec.com/en/products/electroniques.html) the product I've installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the garage where the anti-rust system has been installed and the guy confirmed the problem was the battery terminal connection that got loose.

I don't know if it could have been something else but that solved my problem.